# straight lambda symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

Please suggest how can I get this type of straight lambda, refer image:[image]

Comment: `$\lambda$`? ([code](http://termbin.com/azc8), [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk6qp.png))

Comment: @HenriMenke It produces some slight curve in the top of the symbol, but that line should be a straight line as shown in the image...any how, thanks...

Comment: Then use a font which provides a “straight lambda”.

Comment: @HenriMenke thats what my doubt, unable to identify the correct font name...

Comment: Hope that was related with Mac format TeX, please correct if I am wrong...

Comment: you don't normally want to choose a font separately for each symbol (unless you are writing a ransom note) just choose one font family for all your mathematics